# Electromagnetic waves from current carrying wires

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Consider a current-carrying wire. 
In the first case, the current in the wire is increasing with time. Since the magnetic field is changing, EM waves will be produced. My question is what will be the value of the magnetic component of EM wave. Since the magnetic field due to the wire never becomes zero, will the magnetic component of the EM waves will also be positive? 
In the second case, the current in the wire is changing according to the function $I = 1 + cos(t)$. This current will produce a magnetic field that is increasing and decreasing and always positive. Will the magnetic component of the EM waves also remain positive at all times?

PS: please add some references